# Using JDK 1.8.0_141 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, osx-snow-leopard

I've been trying to get Java 1.8 working on my old Macbook 4.1, using OS X 10.6.8. Now, all versions of Java above 1.6 aren't supported. But I desperately need Java 1.8 for compiling my IntelliJ IDEA projects (I use a lot of Lambda features).

(So I've been able to install Java 1.8 successfully, yet something's not completely right).

**The problem**:
Every time I try to run a Java task, this error occurs:

```
2017-07-23 17:46:58.988 java[629:1a03] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x11676c440 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2017-07-23 17:46:58.991 java[629:1a03] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x11676c440 of class 'ThreadUtilities' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
```

I've been looking all over the web, so all help is appreciated!

P.S. Updating to OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) is not an option for me.

Comment: Try JetBrains JDK from https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/,

Comment: Same error occurs, as well as the JB SDK Bintray Downloader plugin isn't compatible with my version of IntelliJ IDEA (v14).